# Relation between Mertens function and Chebyshev function

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-functions

In Wikipedia article about [Mertens function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function) we can read: "A curious relation given by Mertens himself involving the second Chebyshev function is

$$\displaystyle \psi (x)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } M\left({\frac {x}{n}}\right)\log n=M\left({\frac {x}{2}}\right)\log 2+M\left({\frac {x}{3}}\right)\log 3+M\left({\frac {x}{4}}\right)\log 4+\cdots."$$

**How to prove it?**

$$\Lambda (n)={\begin{cases}\log p&{\text{if }}n=p^{k}{\text{ for some prime }}p{\text{ and integer }}k\geq 1\\0&{\text{otherwise}}\end{cases}}$$

$$\mu(n) ={\begin{cases} +1& {\text{if n is a square-free positive integer with an even number of prime factors}} \\−1& {\text{if n is a square-free positive integer with an odd number of prime factors}}\\0& {\text{if n has a squared prime factor}}\end{cases}}$$

$$\displaystyle \psi (x)=\sum _{n=1}^x \Lambda (n)$$

$$\displaystyle M(x)=\sum _{n=1}^{x}\mu (n)$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the Möbius inversion formula (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula)?

Comment: I know that $\Lambda (n)$ is Möbius inversion of $\log n$ for example, but I am not good at applying Möbius inversion formula.

Comment: Then you're almost there. See the first two lines of formulas in the answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3736052 and substitute $a(n)=\Lambda(n)$, $b(n)=\log(n)$, and $c(n)=\mu(n)$.

Comment: How is that rule called? To be honest I do not see why it holds.